# How can I read url hash to now which page content I should get from database?

Tags: php, jquery, hash

What I'm trying to do is this:

- if the link entered is, per example, "www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php#subpage5" ,
  I want to save "subpage5" to a variable so I can use it to load respective content from mysql database (I'm doing it with php.) if the link entered is "www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php" I want to set the subpage0 was the one to be shown.
- With the page already loaded, I've a left side menu where I have all subpages names linked respectively to href="subpageIndex" - everything is, for now - being loaded from mysql with php as well.
- To finish, I've a click event to thoses left side menu bar links. So, when I click on them the content of my div is uploaded. (Now I'm doing it by reload the page but I think that I cant to it without reloading with AJAX, right? )

**NOTE:** I saw this: http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107   BUT how I can pass to the php file which database entry (identified by the hash) should be selected???

Comment: afaik the hash isn't passed to the server, its browser-only, so you have to use javascript / ajax

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to detect and retrieve the url hash.

Check out `window.location.hash`.

To pass it to PHP for further handling you can use ajax or the simplest way would be to change the window location and pass the variable along with it.

window.location.href = "doSomething.php?hash=" + window.location.hash;

Comment: But how will the php file read the variable if it's not possible to php to read the hash of the url?

Comment: he is passing it as a get variable, so you can use $_GET

Comment: When you pass it to `doSomething.php` you are not passing it as a hash anymore, you are passing it as a variable that can be retrieved through GET. To make things simpler for yourself why don't you use this method in the first place instead of hashes? Hashes cannot be read by PHP so you're making slightly more work for yourself if you're just getting started at this.

Comment: Matt K, I got your idea but I'm not picturing the code I should write.

Comment: Instead of creating links like `www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php#subpage5` why not `www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php?page=subpage5`? It seems like you need a refresher in PHP. Try searching for some online tutorials, specifically on GET and POST data.

Comment: Matt K, I saw it about few minuts ago.

But having your url as an example and then having `<?php $page = $_GET['subpage']; echo $page; ?>` it doesn't work.

Comment: You're passing the variable `page`, but you're reading `subpage`. Name them whatever you want, but they must match.